# Why process invoked by Runtime.getRuntime().exec() has limited memory allocation capability?

Tags: java, memory, process, desktop-application

In my Java 8 application I create new process by calling:

```
Process applicationProcess = Runtime.getRuntime.exec(executionCommand);
```

If executing on Windows 7 64bit + Java 8 64bit (8GB RAM), my `executionCommand` contains the *.exe application path (which is basically a Java application with *.exe launcher and predefined -Xmx 4096m and -Xms 2048m VM options).

Invoked .exe `applicationProcess` instantly creates additional process "B" and closes `Process applicationProcess`, so I loose any reference to process "B" from the inside of my Java application.

While my application is working, **process "B", invoked by command above, has somehow limited memory allocation to ~800MB**. 
This cripples this process, so it doesn't work properly.

If I close my application (while invoked process is still running), suddenly invoked process "B" starts to allocate extra memory according to its predefined VM options and regains proper full efficiency.

Apparently somehow my application limits the memory allocation capabilities for invoked process "B". 
**Why does it happen and how could I bypass this limitation?**

Note: 
1. Setting higher values of -Xmx and -Xms for my java application (invocator) doesn't solve this problem.

Comment: If your observation is correct, then I can only image it has to do with virtual memory address space or job limits. But I am not sure. How do you see that the memory allocation is limited? Does it fail with OOM? Do you mean the VM does start but not have 2GB heap? Or do you mean the resident size is limited? I would asume thats normal as long as it is not touched.

Comment: Normally this process "B" allocates about 1000-1200MB RAM in order to operate normally (memory allocation goes in pair with extensive CPU consumption - about 50% of whole on i7). If this process has insufficient memory allocated, its CPU consumption falls down to 0% and freezes. Unfortunatelly it is an third party application and it doesn't create any work log, so I can't check its state.
After my java application close, process "B" allocates that extra memory above 800MB, regains high CPU load and finishes its task.

Comment: I must admit, that if I start my java application from Netbeans 8.2 - process "B" allocates sufficient memory and everything works properly.

Comment: Sounds like your machine has just not enough RAM, so when 2 JVMs are in memory there is pressure which keeps a lot of the pages paged out. That woukd also explain the poor performance. So it is then not a question of parent/child. I cannot imagine any way a JVM runs without allocating at least Xms and not aborting with OOM if it can't

Comment: I'm afraid, that it's not the point.
1. Launching from Netbeans doesn't cause any issue
2. I have managed to succesfully launch the process "B" via (pseudocode):
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd -C start /wait xxxxxx");`

Comment: Do you consume the output streams in seperate threads?

Comment: Unfortunatelly this process "B" doesn't provide any output streams (really! drops log to fileappenders only), therefore I don't consume output streams at all.